# Creating dropdown form with sql foreign key data

Tags: php, html, mysql

thanks for any help in advance! I want to make a dropdown for my form for the foreign key customerID in my address form, here if the relationship in the table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQSkZ.png

I'd want to make the first name and last name also show in the drop down, I'm very new so apologies if it it's simple, im just trying to practice and get better. 
Here is the code to my add/edit address table, thanks again!

```
<?php

require "DatabaseConn.php";
$submitValue = "Save";
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $custid=$_POST['custid'];
    $add1=$_POST['add1'];
    $add2=$_POST['add2'];
    $add3=$_POST['add3'];
    $postcode=$_POST['postcode'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $county=$_POST['county'];

    if (isset($_GET['CustAdd_ID']))
    {
      $sql = "UPDATE customer_Address SET CustAdd_custID='$custid',CustAdd_addressLine1='$add1',CustAdd_addressLine2 = '$add2',CustAdd_addressLine3 = '$add3',CustAdd_postCode = '$postcode',CustAdd_city = '$city',CustAdd_county = '$county' where CustAdd_ID=".$_GET['CustAdd_ID'];
      $message = "the record has been updated successfully";
    }
    else
    {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customer_Address VALUES (NULL, '$custid', '$add1', '$add2', '$add3', '$postcode', '$city', '$county')";
          $message = "New record created successfully";
    }
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   // echo $message;
   header("location: ViewAddress.php");
} else 
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);   
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><?php include('head.html'); ?>
    <TITLE>Adding Address</TITLE>
<style>
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #679bef;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #4b89ed;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
margin: auto;
}

<?php include 'table.css'; ?> 

<?php include 'cssStyle.css'; ?> 


</style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php include('addeditnavbar.html'); ?>

<?php
$custid ="";
$add1 ="";
$add2="";
$add3 ="";
$postcode ="";
$city ="";
$county ="";

if (isset($_GET['CustAdd_ID']))
{

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_Address where CustAdd_ID=".$_GET['CustAdd_ID'];
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            $custid=$row['CustAdd_custID'];
            $add1=$row['CustAdd_addressLine1'];
            $add2=$row['CustAdd_addressLine2'];
            $add3=$row['CustAdd_addressLine3'];
            $postcode=$row['CustAdd_postCode'];
            $city=$row['CustAdd_city'];
            $county=$row['CustAdd_county'];

            $submitValue = "Save";
}
?>
<div>
   <h2>Customer Address</h2>
  <form action="" method="post">

    <label for="custid">Customer ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="custid" name="custid" value="<?php echo $custid;?>" placeholder="Enter Customer ID..">



    <label for="add1">Address Line 1</label>
    <input type="text" id="add1" name="add1" value="<?php echo $add1;?>" placeholder="Enter Address Line 1..">

    <label for="add2">Address Line 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="add2" name="add2" value="<?php echo $add2;?>" placeholder="Enter Address Line 2..">

    <label for="add3">Address Line 3</label>
    <input type="text" id="add3" name="add3" value="<?php echo $add3;?>" placeholder="Enter Address Line 3..">

    <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
    <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $postcode;?>" placeholder="Enter Postcode">

    <label for="city">City</label>
    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $city;?>" placeholder="Enter City..">

     <label for="county">County</label>
    <input type="text" id="county" name="county" value="<?php echo $county;?>" placeholder="Enter County..">


    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $submitValue;?>">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the query to:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.Cust_firstName as firstname, c.Cust_lastName as lastname, ca.* FROM customer_Address as ca where CustAdd_ID=".$_GET['CustAdd_ID']."LEFT JOIN customer c ON c.Customer_ID=ca.CustAdd_ID";
...
$firstName = $row['firstname'];
$lastName = $row['lastname'];
```

Then in your `html` create 2 inputs and set the values

Comment: Thank you very much, just to clarify do this in the sql for this part?
 https://i.imgur.com/lKMxeY1.png Is it possible to list the cust id, first name, last name in a row on the single drop down or should i just have the first name and last name in a box next to it, that would be easier right?

Comment: Since you are showing the data for one `customer` I would just make one input and show them with space between each, btw, yes, it's that part of the `sql` you showed in a picture

Comment: thank you, I have a view table for address aswell, would it be following the same kind of query for that? thank you for your help means so much <33
 https://pastebin.com/26Zageps

Comment: I would just change the sql in this to something like that then add extra rows in the table for the 
$firstName = $row['firstname'];
$lastName = $row['lastname'];
parts? :)

Comment: Yes, and then you can show them in `input` like you did with the rest